# Local file loading issue in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I am new to JS and NodeJS. The below question might be obvious but can't find the answer anywhere.

I have a file in my local drive. I am trying to load it, testing first if existinging with `fs.exists` or `fs.existsSync()`:

```
fs.existsSync("C:\Temp\myFile.txt")
```

The return I get is that the doesn't exist. Is that because when running, the context is the NodeJS server context? If so how can I access my file?

Comment: I think you will need to escape the slash characters in the path C:\\Temp\\myFile.txt.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly this! Working. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
path: <string> | <Buffer> | <URL>
callback: <Function>
exists:<boolean>
```

Test whether or not the given path exists by checking with the file system. Then call the callback argument with either true or false.

```
fs.exists('C:\\Temp\myFile.txt', (exists) => {
  console.log(exists ? 'it\'s there' : 'no passwd!');
});
```

The parameters for this callback are not consistent with other Node.js callbacks. Normally, the first parameter to a Node.js callback is an error parameter, optionally followed by other parameters. The fs.exists() callback has only one boolean parameter.

Here the documentation link: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback